# (react-native-ble-plx) How to read only those that were gotten after sending request?

Tags: react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy

Is there any way to get response, similar to JavaScripts's fetch(), from ble device using [react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx) package?

I only achieved to add listener and listen to all messages sent by ble device.

Example what I want to achieve:

```
const response = await bleManager.sendMessage(deviceId, serviceUUID, characteristicUUID, message);
```

Comment: To clarify, you want to write to a characteristic and get the response?

Comment: @jnpdx yes, I want to get response for every written characteristic

Comment: https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Characteristic-Writing#with-response

Comment: @jnpdx probably the device I am using has issue, because it returns random value after sending request

Comment: What kind of device are we talking about? What kind of characteristics does it offer? Is it a BLE UART implementation with one RX and one TX characteristic? We need more information

Comment: @MichaelKotzjan it's my brother's project. He is using HM-18 and utinny microchip. I will edit comment when I will get more information about utinny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was searching for was [this](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Characteristic-Writing#with-response). It was show by @jnpdx
My problem is in device I am trying to connect. I hope it helps for someone in the future

Comment: Hey, thanks for coming back with a solution, I'm sure it will help someone in the future. It would be great if you could edit some more information into your answer in case the link does break in the future. At it's current state, your answer would be of little without the link